# How do you display a filesystem URL in a Chrome app webview?

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome packaged app that requires me to be able to view saved, offlined web pages. These pages are downloaded from my server when the user is online and saved to the HTML5 filesystem so that they can be viewed offline.  This Chrome bug ticket seems to indicate that what I want to do is possible: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=343382

Based on the Chrome app 'webview' docs (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), this is what I came up with.

In my manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    {
        "fileSystem": ["write"]
    },
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "webview"
],
"webview": {
    "partitions": [
        {
            "name":"contentView",
            "accessible_resources":["*.html"]
        }
    ]
}
```

My webview tag:

```
<webview id="websiteWebview" minwidth="800" minheight="600" autosize="on" partition="contentView"></webview>
```

And then I'm adding the 'src' attribute through javascript:

```
var websiteWebview = document.querySelector('#websiteWebview');
websiteWebview.setAttribute('src', decodeURIComponent(srcUrl));
```

This results in the following in the console:

```
filesystem:chrome-extension://[appId]/[pathToFile]/index.html
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Not allowed to load local resource: filesystem:chrome-extension://[appId]/[pathToFile]/index.html
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists where you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes. The ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error is a symptom of the webview blocking my local file. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321638

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `webview` tag does not support filesystem URIs - [Chromium Issue 321628](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321638). Bummer.

You could try reading the file to a data URL using a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), then setting the `webview`'s `src` attribute to the URL.

I'm getting around it by using a simple web server I created in NaCl which I've already got embedded in my app (data URLs are messing up my file encoding).

Comment: Hi there, you stated that you got around the issue "by using a simple web server I created in NaCl which I've already got embedded in my app". Could you please elaborate on this or provide a Tutorial or something like that for this topic? Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend the data URL approach if you can get it working, there's way less work involved, and you don't have to know C/C++ - I only had trouble with it because of some crazy file encoding. I used the  [TCPSocket class](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable/cpp/classpp_1_1_t_c_p_socket). And if you're new to NaCl - [NaCl basics](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. So no other way to open (displaying in a webview sense) local files that I've downloaded within the WebApp, eh?

Comment: Nope, not supported by Chrome at present.

Answer (score 0):

You could work around this by including the [web server for chorme](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome) library within your application. There are examples on the site for how to include it in your own chrome app. It would require you to use extra permissions in your manifest, namely some chrome.sockets permissions.