# How do access web app(created by the same chrome app) from filesystem in a Chrome app webview?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-webview

I want to launch a web app created inside filesystem by same chrome app, in webview within chrome web app.

I got the url like:
"filesystem:chrome-extention//path-to-html page"

And given partition permission in webview section in manifest.json as well.
but it throws error file not found.
isthere any way we can access those to launch as webapp.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you display a filesystem URL in a Chrome app webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932960/how-do-you-display-a-filesystem-url-in-a-chrome-app-webview)

Comment: i saw that link given by you but there answers are not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It would require extra permissions (chrome.sockets), but you could include the [web server for chrome](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome) library inside your chrome app and point the webview to the url hosted by the http server.

Comment: it works using iframe as well., should work in web server case too. thanks!

Comment: @kzahel I know it an old question, just want to confirm that we cant access file system files inside web-view correct,? we have to make it work using web server